# How to set a max length for a python list/set?

Tags: python, list, max, maxlength

In c/c++, we could have:

```
maxnum = 10;
double xlist[maxnum];
```

How to set a maximum length for a python list/set?

Comment: so that i can restrict my greedy search to top x number of results. Otherwise it's sort of wasteful to keep appending, sorting then deleting elements after x

Comment: One approach is to create custom class of list and inherit functionality from python `list`. Then in `add` (and maybe others) methods add a check for max length.

Comment: @stalk you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't and do not need to.

Python lists grow and shrink dynamically as needed to fit their contents. Sets are implemented as a hash table, and like Python dictionaries grow and shrink dynamically as needed to fit their contents.

Perhaps you were looking for [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (which takes a `maxlen` parameter) or something using a [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) (using `heapq.heappushpop()` when you have reached the maximum) instead?

Comment: I think you're wrong about dictionaries shrinking, or at least it's somewhat misleading. When I create an empty dict, `sys.getsizeof` tells me it's 148 bytes. After adding a million entries, it's 25165876 bytes. After popping all entries, it's still 25165876 bytes. Also, if I try `next(iter(d))`, after adding the million entries it's about 3500 times faster than after popping all but one (that's actually how I noticed this).

Comment: @StefanPochmann the resize is deferred until you add something again (IIRC). I need to check what the exact triggers are. I do know that the most common usage where you delete is often followed by new adds which is what was optimised for, hence the absence of immediate shrinking on delete.

Comment: @StefanPochmann not at a laptop but this email by Tim Peters explains how a resize is triggered by insertions: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/1999-August/000667.html.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, though might not be correct anymore. When I add items again, my dict stays at 25,165,876 bytes until it eventually jumps to 50,331,700 bytes. [This comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1237) in the current code does say *"the new table may
actually be smaller than the old one"* but I have not been able to actually achieve that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: it is still current, but I haven't studied all the methods by which to trigger the resize. Search for where `dictresize` is actually called.

Comment: @ColonelPanic a `deque` will given you bounded size and expiration-on-insert, but you lose indexed access. I don't see any native queues that support index access or lists that support expiration at max size.

Answer (score 11):

Here is extended version of python's `list`. It behaves like `list`, but will raise `BoundExceedError`, if length is exceeded (tried in python 2.7):

```
class BoundExceedError(Exception):
    pass


class BoundList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.length = kwargs.pop('length', None)
        super(BoundList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _check_item_bound(self):
        if self.length and len(self) >= self.length:
            raise BoundExceedError()

    def _check_list_bound(self, L):
        if self.length and len(self) + len(L) > self.length:
            raise BoundExceedError()

    def append(self, x):
        self._check_item_bound()
        return super(BoundList, self).append(x)

    def extend(self, L):
        self._check_list_bound(L)
        return super(BoundList, self).extend(L)

    def insert(self, i, x):
        self._check_item_bound()
        return super(BoundList, self).insert(i, x)

    def __add__(self, L):
        self._check_list_bound(L)
        return super(BoundList, self).__add__(L)

    def __iadd__(self, L):
        self._check_list_bound(L)
        return super(BoundList, self).__iadd__(L)

    def __setslice__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 2 and self.length:
            left, right, L = args[0], args[1], args[2]
            if right > self.length:
                if left + len(L) > self.length:
                    raise BoundExceedError()
            else:
                len_del = (right - left)
                len_add = len(L)
                if len(self) - len_del + len_add > self.length:
                    raise BoundExceedError()
        return super(BoundList, self).__setslice__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> l = BoundList(length=10)
>>> l.extend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> # now all these attempts will raise BoundExceedError:
>>> l.append(11)
>>> l.insert(0, 11)
>>> l.extend([11])
>>> l += [11]
>>> l + [11]
>>> l[len(l):] = [11]
```

Comment: do i need to import any library or something?

Answer (score 10):

Once you have your list, `lst`, you can

```
if len(lst)>10:
    lst = lst[:10]
```

If size more than 10 elements, you truncate to first ten elements.

Comment: as @JonasR points out, checking `len(lst)` before truncating is redundant.

Comment: try this code `x=[1,2,6]; x = x[:2] if len(x)>2 else x` and then try this code `x=[1,2,6]; x[:2]`

Answer (score 3):

You can't, lists and sets are dynamic in nature and can grow to any size.

Python is not c++, python is a dynamic language. Sets and list can expand or shrink to any size.

Use [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#module-heapq) module if you want x smallest or largest items from an iterable.

```
heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable[, key])
```

> Return a list with the n smallest elements from the dataset defined by
>   iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that
>   is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable:
>   key=str.lower Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]

Or may be [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

> This module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order
>   without having to sort the list after each insertion.

Then use slicing or  `itertools.slice` to get top x items from the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution that allocate memory first

```
[0] * maxnum
```

or

```
[a sample of your object] * maxnum
```

Note that this solution doesn't throw error such as c++ language if it is append more than maximum size of list