# Pythonic way to set a maximum length parameter

Tags: python, max, maxlength

**What is the pythonic way to set a maximum length paramter?**

Let's say I want to restrict a list of strings to a certain maximum size:

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']
>>> maxlen = 3
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
['foo', 'bar', 'a']
```

And I want to functionalize it and allow different maxlen but if no maxlen is given, it should return the full list:

```
def func1(alist, maxlen):
  return [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
```

And I want to set the maxlen to the max length of element in alist, so I tried but I am torn between using `None`, `0` or `-1`.

If I use `None`, it would be hard to cast the type later on:

```
def func1(alist, maxlen=None):
  if maxlen == None:
    maxlen = max(alist, key=len)
  return [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
```

And I might get this as the function builds on:

```
>>> maxlen = None
>>> int(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
>>> type(maxlen)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

If I use -1, it sort of resolve the `int(maxlen)` issues but it's also sort of weird since length should never be negative.

```
def func1(alist, maxlen=-1):
  if maxlen < 0:
    maxlen = max(alist, key=len)
  return [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
```

If I use 0, I face the problem when I really need to return an empty list and set `maxlen=0` but then again, if I really need an empty list then I don't even need a function to create one.

```
def func1(alist, maxlen=0):
  if maxlen == 0:
    maxlen = max(alist, key=len)
  return [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
```

(Note: the ultimate task is NOT to filter a list, i.e. `(filter(lambda k: len(k) <= maxlen, lst))` but it's an example to ask about the pythonic way to set an integer variable that sets a maximum)

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but just wanted to point you to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526659/how-to-set-a-max-length-for-a-python-list-set

Comment: How about using  `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')` as default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I want to restrict a list of strings to a certain maximum
>   size:
>
> And I want to functionalize it and allow different maxlen but if no
>   maxlen is given, it should return the full list:
>
> And I want to set the maxlen to the max length of element in alist

To address all these requests, the best answer I can think of is something like this...

```
def func(lst, ln=None):
    if not ln:
        return lst
    ln = max(ln, len(lst))
    return [i for i in lst if len(i) <= ln]
```

---

**edit:**

If it is important to handle negative maximum length (who knows why) or 0 length, then a function like this can be used. (Though I am against duck-typing)

```
def func(lst, ln=None):
    if ln is None:
        return lst
    elif ln < 1:  # handles 0, and negative values.
        return []
    else:
        ln = max(ln, len(lst))
        return [i for i in lst if len(i) <= ln]
```

Comment: is `max(ln, len(lst))` expensive if my lst in size of 3,000,000?

Comment: `if not ln:` --> This is also true for `ln = 0` and thus will return the full list. The list comprehension would return an empty list for `ln=0`. Depending on the exact requirements you might have to distinguish these two cases.

Comment: @OcasoProtal OP mentioned that for `ln=0` it is irrelevant because it's basically an empty list. `"If I use 0, I face the problem when I really need to return an empty list and set maxlen=0 but then again, if I really need an empty list then I don't even need a function to create one."`

Comment: @alvas No, `len()` function on any list size is O(1) complexity.

Comment: See updated function which considers duck-typing scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following approach, this avoids the need to use `max`:

```
def filter_length(a_list, max_length=None):
    if max_length == 0:
        return []
    elif max_length:
        return [i for i in x if len(i) <= max_length]
    else:
        return a_list

x = ['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']

print filter_length(x, 3)
print filter_length(x)
print filter_length(x, 0)
```

Giving you the output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'a']
['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about some tricks?.. Operator `or` returns first value, if both values are `True`. And, if first value is `False` and second is `True`, `or` returns second value.

```
>>> m = 3
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= m] or x
['foo', 'bar', 'a']
>>> m = 0
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= m]
[]
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= m] or x
['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']
```

I think it's just what you need. :-)

Ough... I forget about `-1` and `None`. Result will be the same:

```
>>> m = None
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= m] or x
['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']
>>> m = -1
>>> [i for i in x if len(i) <= m] or x
['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said: "*I want to allow different `maxlen`s but if no `maxlen` is given, it should return the full list*".
An approach would be a definition of a `maxFilter()` function which uses Pythons **[*default argument values*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)**:

```
>>> def maxFilter(alist, maxlen = None):
        if maxlen is None:
           #no maxlen is given -> return full list
           return alist
        else:
           #in all other cases apply algorithm  
           return [i for i in x if len(i) <= maxlen]
```

Examples, using `x = ['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']`:

```
>>> maxFilter(x, None) #same as maxFilter(x)
['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'rushmoreorless', 'kilimangogo']

>>> maxFilter(x, 3)
['foo', 'bar', 'a']

>>> maxFilter(x, 0)
[]
```

**Note:** In my opinion it would be better to ask about a way *to set an **optional** length parameter to list elments* .